# Date and Time format in MySQL and HTML

Tags: html, mysql, date, time, format

I have a database with 5 columns, where 2 of them are `date` and `time`. In MySQL, date format is `YYYY-MM-DD`. I'm trying to create a web application to insert values into that database, but I have a problem because date format in HTML is `mm/dd/yyyy`.

There is a part of HTML code:

```
Date_input : <input type="date" name="Datum">
```

How can I solve that? Which format should I choose, or how can I convert one format to another?

Comment: What intermediary back-end language are you using to send the HTML input to the database?

Comment: I'm using PHP.  I've tried to enter year, month and day as text values. I've stored those three values into one variable ($date1). After that I've used commad: $realdate = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($date1)); but it still can't upload into database. When i type echo $realdate I see I have appropriate format yyyy-mm-dd, and I realy don't know why that value can't be uploaded.